# Where can i find animal armatures?

Tags: rigging, rigify

Blender site tutorial (last intro one) shows human (meta-rig) and animal rigs but I only see the human option. Is there a download to get animal rigs installed?

Comment: are you using blender 2.79? because the rigify addon was updated with the 2.79 release. That update includes all the new rig types.

Answer (score 5):

IN the User Preferences, enable the Rigify addon (2.79)[image] and then in the add menu under armature, you will find the other rigs.[image]